# Medium App like UITableView Implementation

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, ios7

I would like to implement my UITableView as seen in the new app by Medium. The implementation is quite similar to the iOS photos app.

The basic concept is slide down for scroll view and slide left or right for next article.

What would be the best way to implement such an animation, if any open source classes available let me know.

iTunes Link for Medium: https://itunes.apple.com/app/medium-everyones-stories/id828256236?mt=8

Comment: Did you get article loading issues on UITableViewCell ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your down scrolling I would suggest a normal `UITableView`.

I found a tutorial for creating a PageViewController.
..this is more like an Introduction than a ScrollView for the next article.
http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-tutorial-intro/

I hope this will help you!